# LaTeX fonts without XeTeX?

Tags: fonts

I've been trying for a long time, and can find no good results of how to use a font from a file with LaTeX. Every website I've found about this tells me to do it in a way that is too complicated, i'm just looking for the easy way to do this. The goal is to be able to download a new file, and use it in LaTeX easily each time. There is no specific way I want to do that, but it can not involve using XeTeX.

Comment: your question is not very clear. you mean you want to download any font and use with pdftex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more complicated than using a modern font in LuaTeX or XeTeX, but not impossibly so.

Let’s take as an example the font URW Classico, a clone of Optima that comes in both legacy Type 1 and modern OpenType formats.  The process is similar for most of the legacy fonts out there.

First, download [the package archive on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classico), or whatever other site you trust.

Next, save the files to your local TeX tree.  On TeX Live, you can find your local TeX tree with the command `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`.  On MikTeX, you would have to set one up in the MikTeX console.

Next, make sure the files you just installed are in your index.  On TeX Live, the command for this is `texhash` (or `mktexlsr` will also work).  You should run this with whatever privileges you used to install TeX.  Usually, this is root/Administrator, bur I always use `sudo -u tex` to update my installation.

Now that the files in the package are indexed, you should update the font map, with

```
updmap-sys --enable Map classico.map
```

Or whatever the `.map` files are named in your archive.  This should also run with the same permissions as your TeX installation.  Remember to always use `updmap-sys`!  If you run `updmap --user` by mistake, it will appear to work at first, but the new map it creates will hide any updates to the system font map.

You should now be able to use this file in legacy TeX with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{classico}
```

There is also a [script from TUG](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) that you can use to install URW Classico and many other fonts.

Comment: Of course, for classico one should use `getnonfreefonts`.

Comment: @egreg That has a unique installation procedure that made it a bad example. I suppose I might’ve used `emerald`.

Comment: It's not a bad example! But suggesting `getnonfreefonts` was needed.

Comment: @egreg Okay, I added a note about it.

Comment: May want to make it clear that this will only work for fonts for which LaTeX support has been added, and is available on CTAN. (It won't work for a random font downloaded from https://fonts.google.com/?sort=date say.) (The question mentions *"The goal is to be able to download a new file, and use it in LaTeX easily each time."* and I'm not sure whether "file" there means "(arbitrary) font".)